# DynamoDB to S3 parquet without Glue but with transformation and file naming

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I would like to take a single DynamoDB table which contains a `data` field with JSON data. This data has a schema that is dependent on the user associated with the table entry. Let's assume that the schema is part of the entry for simplicity.

I would like to stream this data into S3 as Parquet with embedded schema, transformation (i.e. just sending the `data` field) and custom file naming based on the user ID.

I am using CDK v2.

What I found so far:

- I can go from DynamoDB to Kinesis Stream to Firehose but Glue is required - I don't need it nor sure how I would provide it with these various "dynamic" schemas.
- CDK asks for the S3 filename - I see there may be the possibility of a dynamic field in the name but not sure how I would use that (i've seen date for ex - I would need it to be something coming from the transform lambda),
- I think that using Kinesis stream directly in DynamoDB config may not be what I want and I should just use regular DB streams but then.... Would I transform data, pass this to a Firehose? where does file naming etc come in.

I've read so many docs but all seem to deal with a standard table to file and Athena.

Summary: How can I append streaming dynamodb data to various parquet file and transform/determine file name from a lambda in the middle. I think I have to go from a dyanamodb stream lambda handler and append directly to S3 but not finding too much in examples. Concerned about buffering etc

Comment: Is a batch approach an option? if you enalbe Point-in-time recovery for your table then u can have DynamoDB to S3 (https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-export-amazon-dynamodb-table-data-to-data-lake-amazon-s3/) export out of the box. Then a single athena query can do ETL and save the results back to S3 as parquets (https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/athena-query-output-different-format/).

Comment: It could be but the 35 day limit is what blocked me though I may be unclear - I don't think I can get a single parquet file from say 2 years of data on there

Comment: Do u need a single parquet? you can do `PARTITIONED BY (...)` to split the data. 35 days is max retention period. Data in s3 can be stored as long as you want. I think you can export DynamoDB to S3 json (set lifecycle policy to keep data for a day or two to save costs) then Athena from S3 json to S3 parquet (keep it as long as it is required). if athena is not good, I guess you can EMR the data with SPARK and save it in any format you like

Comment: @Anton I wanted to try DuckDB with parquet and be able to analyze whatever was in DynamoDB - say 2-3 years up to now. Duck DB can load multiple files. But this is not a real time sync though - sounds like I would need to call the export

Comment: Well, @cyberwombat, you can have nearly real-time by creating small files using DynamoDB stream to Lambda to S3 parquet. However this way you may end up having gazillion small parquet files not sure how tolerant to many files DuckDB is. At some point you need to transform them.